# Image resizing, IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing, index-error

I have the assignment to scale/ resize an image without the use functions from external libraries and need to create the algorithm myself, have searched, but the code that I have found on different forums have not worked, but I have come up with a code that I would believe would work, but I get the index error on a side note I also need to make forward and backward mapping in relation to scaling the image.

My code can be seen below

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('Scale.jpg', 1)
cv.imshow('unscaled', img)
h,w = img.shape[:2]
print(h)
print(w)
def resizePixels(pixels,w1,h1,w2,h2) :

   retval = [w2,h2]
   # EDIT: added +1 to remedy an early rounding problem
   x_ratio = (int)((w1<<16)/w2) +1
   y_ratio = (int)((h1<<16)/h2) +1
   #int x_ratio = (int)((w1<<16)/w2)
   #int y_ratio = (int)((h1<<16)/h2)
   #two = int(x2,y2)
   for i in range (h2):
     i += 1
    for j in range(w2):
        j += 1
        x2 = ((j*x_ratio)>>16)
        y2 = ((i*y_ratio)>>16)
        retval[(i*w2)+j] = pixels[(y2*w1)+x2]

   return retval;

dst = resizePixels(img,h,w,300,300)

#cv.imshow('Resize',dst)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

EDIT: This is the Traceback I receive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Asus/PycharmProjects/Scaling/Scaling.py", line 27, in 
<module>
dst = resizePixels(img,h,w,300,300)

File "C:/Users/Asus/PycharmProjects/Scaling/Scaling.py", line 23, in 
resizePixels

retval[(i*w2)+j] = pixels[(y2*w1)+x2]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

[The picture I use to scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D90X.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make some little changes in your code and it works. Read my comment in the code for more detail.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
cv2.imshow('unscaled', img)

h,w = img.shape[:2]
print(h)
print(w)
def resizePixels(pixels,w1,h1,w2,h2):
    retval = []
    # EDIT: added +1 to remedy an early rounding problem
    x_ratio = (int)((w1<<16)/w2) +1
    print(x_ratio)
    y_ratio = (int)((h1<<16)/h2) +1
    print(y_ratio)
    #int x_ratio = (int)((w1<<16)/w2)
    #int y_ratio = (int)((h1<<16)/h2)
    #two = int(x2,y2)
    for i in range(h2):
        # no need to have this: i += 1
        for j in range(w2):
            # no need to have this too: j += 1
            x2 = ((j*x_ratio)>>16)
            y2 = ((i*y_ratio)>>16)
            #add pixel values from original image to an array
            retval.append(pixels[y2,x2])

    return retval;

ret = resizePixels(img,w,h,300,300)
# reshape the array to get the resize image
dst = np.reshape(ret,(300,300))

cv2.imshow('Resize',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]